# Breakpoint in passing data from a view controller to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, segue

I am writing a simple note app that consists of a navigation controller. The root view has a table view, which when clicked on, pushes to a second view. The name of the row clicked would then be passed to the second view controller and used as the title in the nav bar.

Right now, when I run the code, the app reaches a `breakpoint` when I click on a table view item. The `breakpoint` points to the second line from the bottom in the following `prepareForSegue` method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showNote"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        // JAYShowNoteViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        // destViewController.noteName = [allNotes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        JAYShowNoteViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
        destination.noteName = [allNotes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

I did a lot of searching and editing of my own, but I could not find a solution to this problem.

Comment: @NSIllusion The app reaches a `breakpoint` when I click on a table view item, and I'm not sure why it's happening.

Comment: JAYShowNoteViewController *destination = (JAYShowNoteViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable breakpoints from Xcode while you running the app. check below screen shot to disable the break points.

[image]

Comment: Oh wow. Stupid me. I thought breakpoints referred to an error in the code that would cause an app to stop working from there on.

Answer (score 2):

BreakPoint is not an indicator of error , it use to check stepByStep flow of our running code.

You can disable your all breakPoint by clicking on that icon

[image: Click on Breakpoints]